# Load specific <div> content into WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

I have tried parse out  with JSoup and load  it into  WebView via [loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), but it is relatively slow and needs to be edited with custom CSS.

Fastest option for now is to load JavaScript function to filter content of web page. What would be the best way using JavaScript to get only content_center 
`<div id="content_center">Only this content needs to be displayed in WebView</div`>  display from this [page](http://www.ffzg.unizg.hr/infoz/hr/index.php/lanovi-odsjeka/).

Preferably while page is loading so the user doesn't have to see the changes happening on their screens while JavaScript is doing its job.
Right now from this code my layout in WebView is affected by bg_wrapper, while content_center is displayed.

```
 @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +

                    "document.getElementById('logo_section').style.display='none';"+
                    "document.getElementById('top').style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementById('bg_wrapper').style.display='hidden'; " +
                    "document.getElementById('left').style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementById('right').style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementById('content_center').style.display='visible'; " +
                    "})()");

            if(pd.isShowing()){
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
```